# Inserting adjustable delay on each Input Source

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm currently using Naudio to create a mixer with multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

For each input, while the audio is playing, I would like to be able to add a sample sized delay whenever I choose to.
The effect will be similar to pausing for, say 100 samples, and then playing again. 
For example, a mixingSampleProvider is currently playing audio to output Channel 5, using multiplexingSampleProvider. On a certain button click, i would like to delay mixingSampleProvider by 200 samples, before it continues playing from the point it paused for a moment.

I would like to know if it's possible to do so, and what options can be looked at to achieve this effect.

Edit: 
The specific problem which requires fixing, would be the knowledge gap I have in inserting Zeros to the buffer, while pushing all the rest of the samples back, while audio is playing. Here, I'm not looking for code to be written, but am looking for resources to attempt to create a new class to solve this issue. Or whether it is even possible at all.

Edit 2: Code I have tried (failed)

```
 public int Read(float[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int sampleRead = source.Read(buffer,offset,count);
        int delaySamples = Math.Min(count, DelayBySamples - delayPos);
        float[] copyBuffer = buffer;

        for (int n = 0; n < delaySamples;n++ )
        {
            buffer[offset + n] = 0;
        }
        for (int n = 0; n < sampleRead;n++ )
        {
            buffer[offset + delaySamples + n] = copyBuffer[offset+n];
        }


        delayPos += delaySamples;
        sampleRead += delaySamples;


        return sampleRead;
    }
```

Comment: SO is a site to come to with a specific problem that needs fixing.  Simply giving a vague description of a task and asking people to write code is not going to get a good answer, and is likely to get your question closed.  Showing some code examples and research of things you've tried will improve your chances of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this by creating your own custom `ISampleProvider` that wraps each input to your mixer (Decorator pattern). Then have a method that tells it to insert n samples of silence. Then in the `Read` method of your SampleProvider if silence is required, then put up to the desired number of silent samples into the read buffer. And when the pause finishes, start returning samples from the source provider again.

You can have a look at the source code to the `OffsetSampleProvider` for inspiration, which allows you to add a specified number of silence samples at the start of your stream.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have looked very closely at both 'OffsetSampleProvider' and 'BufferedWaveProvider' for inspiration. I would like to further inquire why I cannot use 'float[] copyBuffer = buffer', then inserting the copyBuffer back after I created a buffer of zeroes.